# Corona SDK Memory Leak

Tags: memory, coronasdk

I'm writing a game using Corona for a game design class and though I'm still learning, I've got most of the basics down. Right now, I have a situation where the program slows down after about two minutes or so of playing, and I'm not entirely sure why. I've already implemented code to remove all bodies which have served their purpose and I even have it set up to print a notification when each one is removed.

http://www.mediafire.com/?5fz7ru0c6euwq1k

This is the download link. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

First off, have you checked the memory usage? If the problem gradually slows down that certainly sounds like a memory leak, but you need to check the memory usage to be sure. Print out memory usage to the console like so:

```
print("mem "..collectgarbage("count"))
```

Put that in an enterFrame listener so that you can watch the memory usage continuously while your app is running.

Now once you are seeing the memory consumed by your app, the most crucial step in any sort of debugging is isolating the problem. That is, zero in on the spot in the code that causes the problem. For some problems you can rely on techniques like printing debug messages to the console, but for a memory leak your best bet is often to selectively comment out sections of the code to see what affect that has on memory.

For example, first comment out the event listeners on one screen and then check the memory usage. If the leak is gone, then you know the problem was something to do with those event listeners. If the leak is unaffected, then restore those event listeners and comment out the next possible cause of a memory leak. rinse and repeat

Once you know the exact section of code that is causing the leak, you will probably be able to see what you need to fix. If not, ask about that specific code.